# Дилемма: двоеточие или точка с запятой

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, двоеточие, точка-с-запятой

У меня с моим старым знакомым (он лингвист по образованию) возник спор: какие знаки препинания ставить в предложении "В глубинах океана у берегов Австралии нашли два странных организма(; или :) они не могут быть причислены ни к одному биологическому семейству".
Я считаю, что здесь может ставиться точка с запятой или запятая. Аргументирую я это тем, что первая часть предложения не слишком сильно связана со второй, в моём понимании, ведь в первой даётся информации о нахождении организмов, а во втором предложении даётся информация о классификации этих организмов. Мой знакомый утверждает, что единственный возможный знак — это двоеточие, ведь здесь формируется причинная связь (можно поставить вместо двоеточия "потому что"). Я никогда не видел того, чтобы причинная связь формировалась с определением в предложении. Кто прав?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*В глубинах океана у берегов Австралии нашли два **странных** организма: они не могут быть причислены ни к одному биологическому семейству.*

Здесь **пояснительное значение**, то есть объясняется, в чем их странность. При постановке **двоеточия** делается увеличенная пауза, предупреждающая о последующем пояснении (интонационное предупреждение по Розенталю, классический вариант оформления).

Если паузу не подчеркивать, то можно использовать присоединительное **тире**:

*В глубинах океана у берегов Австралии нашли два **странных** организма – они не могут быть причислены ни к одному биологическому семейству.*

Для сравнения: *Найденные в глубинах океана у берегов Австралии два организма выглядят **странно**: они не могут быть причислены ни к одному биологическому семейству.*

Постановка тире также возможна. В этом случае вторая часть может выражать **и причину** (= так как), и **пояснять** значение наречия "странно".

Answer (score 1):

Примеры (из Нацкорпуса) фраз подобной конструкции показывают, что не стоит ограничивать себя в выборе вариантов пунктуации ( ; или : ).
Правда и ложь это не люди, они не могут быть терпимыми или нетерпимыми ― терпимость это свойство личности. [коллективный. Форум: Православие и «Русский марш» (2012)]
Ведь любая повесть имеет в виду, что герои ее ― отсутствующие, они не могут быть прямо здесь. [Ксения Голубович. «Тристан и Изольда» в исполнении Ольги Седаковой // «Волга», 2011]
Мальчик озлобленно подшучивает над стариком, мол, одни и те же пирожки с самого утра, они не могут быть свежими. [Александр Иличевский. Перс (2009)]
Богу, которому ты веришь, неугодны такие жертвы. Они не могут быть угодны… Подумай, Ирина, разве он не знал счастья в жизни? [Ф. Е. Зарин-Несвицкий. За чужую свободу (1910)]
— О, они здоровы! — отвечал он иронически, ― они не могут быть больны: им неизвестны страдания! [М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Противоречия (1847)]
Любовь ― она наполняет их сердца; они не могут быть один без другого; они умирают, когда не видятся. [А. И. Клушин. Несчастный М-в (1793)]

Что касается собственно спорной фразы, то при ее переводе с «беглого устного» на «письменный» может получиться:
…нашли два странных организма. Их нельзя причислить ни к одному известному биологическому семейству.
…нашли два организма, необычных настолько, что они не могут быть причислены...

Comment: Себя ограничивать по возможности не стоит ни в чем :) Что касается конкретного предложения, то всегда один из вариантов в чем-то лучше всех остальных.  Конечно, нужен контекст, но в данном сучае не стоит делить фразу на две части: мысль, как я полагаю, должна быть продолжена в том же предложении.

Comment: Соглашаюсь с Вашим, Sharon, замечанием. Предложенный мной вариант с делением фразы на две части "смотрится" неважно.

Comment: Спасибо вам за понимание.